# Is there a possibility to remove the inset for a specific section or row in a tableview with the style .insetGrouped?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to remove the inset for the first section so that the collection view goes to the edge of the screen but at the same time preserving the tableview style .insetGrouped so that the section below is displayed in a card layout view with rounded corners?
The collection view is in a separate section and the content below is also in a separate section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could fix it on my own.
Solution:
You can set your own tableview header view which has the width of the screen and the appropriate height.
Add your collectionView to the collectionViewTableViewHeaderView and thats it.

```
let collectionViewTableViewHeaderView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 210))
tableView.tableHeaderView = collectionViewTableViewHeaderView
```